# Adult comic about a robot that exterminated all organic life

Tags: story-identification, comics, robots

It was about a robot who had exterminated all organic life in the universe, but hates his job, and later gets divorced by his wife. He also has a son that curses a lot, and later saves his world from aliens.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  About when did you read this?  You should check out the other [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [edit] in anything else you recall.

Comment: Curious: if all organic life was exterminated, where did the aliens come from?

Comment: [Manhunters (DC Comics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhunters_(DC_Comics))?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can of course accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

[*D4VE*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/25650179-d4ve) by Ryan Ferrier

[image: Front cover of *D4VE*]

> Primetime TV; mortgages; traffic jams. The robots conquered earth, wiping out all life in the galaxy, but nothing changed. Meet D4VE, the greatest robot war hero, now trapped behind a desk at a soul-sucking day job. Can something, somewhere snap him out of this slump? Will a new presence on 34RTH ignite his long-lost spark for battle?

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1959617519?book_show_action=true) mentions more matching details:

> The robots rose up and destroyed us...but were unable to escape the legacy of human thinking, so continue to exist in a simulacrum of late capitalism, where Bad Boys 5 has just been released, mild cursing runs to 'Jobsdamned' and 'William H Gates', and a robot husband haplessly claims the shop was out of oil despite it being the only thing they consume. D4VE was a war hero once; now he's a schlub with an office job he hates, an arsehole boss he hates, and a newly-ordered teenage son who doesn't respect him and is constantly wanking. Despite, as I may have mentioned, all of them being robots. But then, oh happy day, a time again comes when the robots need somebody to kick some ass while delivering improbable one-liners...

Found with a search for `funny comic book robot exterminates all human life`